# Resize background-image before applying contain/cover

Tags: css, flexbox, background-image, background-size

## General question:

I want to resize a CSS background image (without keeping the aspect ratio) and *then* apply a `background-size: contain` to that same image. Doing it the other way around would somewhat cancel out the effect of the `contain` option.

Can this be done with HTML/CSS or is it necessary to bring Javascript into this? Editing the images manually beforehand is not doable in my use case.

## My use case:

http://jsfiddle.net/h5a2nxfd/68/

I have some pictures I'd like to display with altered aspect ratio side-to-side or top-to-bottom, depending on whether landscape or portrait mode is active. The JSFiddle above lacks the size altering.

I have tried using `transform` to apply scaling, but in the current solution the width/height of `div.item` is variable so it is not very doable.

I'm open to your suggestions. I might be trying to approach this problem from a wrong angle. But I'd prefer to not use Javascript.

EDIT: Added circles to the sample SVG images used in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Just a note: it might be more helpful to use sample background images that are like circles or something in your code snippet, since with the solid color rectangles it is impossible to tell the difference from looking at them whether they've been skewed to a different aspect ratio or simply clipped.

Comment: How do you decide the altered aspect ratio that you want ?

Comment: @kenS good point. I updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: @vals The desired aspect ratio is constant and known beforehand, and currently will be the same for all pictures in question. The desired aspect ratio currently is 4:3.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an HTML and CSS solution, rather than just a pure CSS solution, the following works by nesting the images inside a `div`, letting you split up the flex item sizing styles and image sizing styles more effectively. You can set styles on the flex item to determine the size of the box that the `.image` will be contained within, and/or set a width and height on the `.image` itself to skew the aspect ratio of the image. Note that in order to do this more responsively, rather than setting fixed widths and heights on the container I have created [fixed-aspect-ratio](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) containers for `.image`. You can change the aspect ratio based on your needs. I have also used `img`s instead of `div`s with background images, which give you a little bit more control over aspect ratios right out of the box (ie unlike for a `div` an explicit width and `height: auto;` on an `img` will result in preserving the aspect ratio, and so will `width: auto;` and an explicit height, which could be useful when your layout switches from a row-based flexbox layout to a column-based one).

Another potential benefit which using `img` tags rather than `div`s with background images would enable is the use the `object-fit: contain;` property (or `object-fit: scale-down;` if you want the image to only scale down and never up) rather than setting the image's width and height to 100% of a container constrained to the appropriate aspect ratio or using `background-size: contain;` on a `div` with a background image. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) for a reference on `object-fit`, including browser support info.

Here is a working code snippet with `img` tags placed within aspect ratio boxes, with their aspect ratios not being preserved as the question requests:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("portrait");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: auto;/*you had this as 100%. If you are going to constrain the height of your container, then you need to constrain the height of the items too to make sure they still fit inside, ie put max-height: 50%; on the items inside the container.*/
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*align-items: stretch;*//*align-items: stretch; will cause potential problems with your layout if you intend for there to be more than 1 item per row/column*/
}

/*body.portrait .container {
  flex-direction: column;
}*/

.item {
  /*flex-grow: 1;*//*flex-grow: 1; will likewise cause potential problems with your layout if you intend for there to be more than 1 item per row/column*/
  width: 50%;/*can use width auto with images that have an intrinsic width to let image size determine width, or can set an explicit width as I have done here (for 1 image per row 100%, for 2 images per row 50%, etc)*/
}

.aspect-ratio-box-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 0 75%;
  margin: 0;
}

.aspect-ratio-box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.item .image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body.portrait .aspect-ratio-box-outer {
  padding: 0 0 133.33333%;
}


/* The images are inline SVG for demonstration purposes only */
/*.item.first {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='500' height='400'><rect width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: red' /><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='150' style='fill: black' /></svg>");
}*/
/*.item.second {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='500' height='400'><rect width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: blue' /><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='150' style='fill: black' /></svg>");
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Stackoverflow question</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Click to toggle between landscape and portrait mode.
  </p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item first">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-outer">
        <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inner">
          <!--<div class="image"></div>-->
    <img class="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='500' height='400'><rect width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: red' /><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='150' style='fill: black' /></svg>" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item second">
      <div class="aspect-ratio-box-outer">
        <div class="aspect-ratio-box-inner">
          <!--<div class="image"></div>-->
    <img class="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='500' height='400'><rect width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: blue' /><circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='150' style='fill: black' /></svg>" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see a couple issues with the solution you provided code for, though. I need the images to occupy as much space of the container as possible, while still being "contained", but your solution does not respond to the window being resized (see how my JSFiddle responds to resizing). An easier to fix thing is that in portrait mode, the aspect ratio should still be 4:3, but not 3:4. But again, thanks for your thoughts. I would be interested to see the fixed-aspect-ratio boxes and img tag solutions, too.

Comment: Yeah, that would mean you should use the aspect ratio boxes rather than the fixed width ones in my current snippet. Feel free to give it a try based on the css-tricks link in my post. I'm busy most of today but will update my answer to include a demo of aspect ratio boxes when I get a chance

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the aspect ratio boxes and also `img` tags rather than `div`s with background images. The snippet does what I understand you to be asking for, skewing the images and not preserving their aspect ratio rather than clipping them to fit within your desired 4:3 aspect ratio containers.

Comment: I created a modification of your solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/h5a2nxfd/74/
Unfortunately the solution does not handle cases when there's not enough screen height to accommodate the images. If there is not enough screen height, the images should be resized to fit into the container (like they are in the JSFiddle of the original post).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve, try setting background-size to 100% instead of contain